# Reading and Editing Firebase Database JSON file [Nodejs]

Tags: json, node.js, file, firebase-realtime-database

I have a file named data.json that has data that looks like below. Its from a firebase database.

```
[
     "-L1PW1Gt_34w1xb32BK5" : {
  "Article_Headline" : "Mobay flood victims receive help from ministry",
  "Article_Image_URL" : "https://www.wefornews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/news-3.jpg",
  "Article_Published_Date" : "Wed, 27 Dec 2017 23:02:53 GMT",
  "Article_URL" : "http://www.jamaicaobserver.com/latestnews/Mobay_flood_victims_receive_help_from_ministry?profile=1228",
  "Category" : "riots,",
  "Location" : "Jamaica",
  "Source_Name" : "jamaica observer",
  "Tags" : "SocialSecurity,LabourParty,MontegoBay,Horsepower,JIS,Jamaica,USRoute36,AndrewHolness"
},
]
```

I want my data to look like this

```
 {
     "Article_Headline" : "Mobay flood victims receive help from ministry",
     "Article_Image_URL" : "https://www.wefornews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/news-3.jpg",
     "Article_Published_Date" : "Wed, 27 Dec 2017 23:02:53 GMT",
     "Article_URL" : "http://www.jamaicaobserver.com/latestnews/Mobay_flood_victims_receive_help_from_ministry?profile=1228",
     "Category" : "riots,",
     "Location" : "Jamaica",
     "Source_Name" : "jamaica observer",
     "Tags" : "SocialSecurity,LabourParty,MontegoBay,Horsepower,JIS,Jamaica,USRoute36,AndrewHolness"
     "key": "-L1PW1Gt_34w1xb32BK5" 
   }
```

What code can be used to produce such a result?

Here is my code below which doesn't work

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = fs.readFileSync('./data.json', 'utf8');


function snapshotToArray(obj) {
var returnArr = [];

obj.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var item = childSnapshot.val();
    item.key = childSnapshot.key;

    returnArr.push(item);
});

return returnArr;
};

console.log(snapshotToArray(obj));
```

Comment: but what you have mentioned above is not a valid json

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code :)

Comment: just require that file simple

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare what would make it valid JSON??

Comment: use this to validate your json https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

In general, given that the JSON is valid:

```
import fs from 'fs';
const obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data.json', 'utf8'));
const data_to_keep = obj.the_key_of_data_to_keep;
delete obj.the_key_of_data_to_keep;
```

Now the property, `the_key_of_data_to_keep`, is deleted but you still have a reference to its value through `data_to_keep` which you can insert somewhere in `obj` for example.